# AES256 CBC encryption/decryption in objective C. Getting null value in decryption. I am already having the encrypted value with me

Tags: objective-c

```
// Code to decrypt value

 { 
 NSString *dataString = @"8T79ubuRfEwpfSOO1yr3Q+nbsla4J7VqFCe4THnPOGxjk37+2QgdLUgq5yWqLtx+";
 NSString *base64Key  =  @"82a645babc6vd41c9a2cb4d0d3ba17ad";
 NSString *base64KeyIv  = @"acf30ad62b693849";
 NSData *key  = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Key  options:0];

NSData *keyiv  = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64KeyIv  options:0];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:dataString options:0];

NSData *encryptedData = [ViewController crypt:data
                                 iv:keyiv
                                key:key
                            context:kCCDecrypt];

  NSString *decryptText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData 
  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"Decrypted Result: %@", decryptText);   //here getting NULL

 }
```

I am getting null value while decryption.Please help me where I am wrong. AES256 CBC encryption/decryption in objective C. Getting null value in decryption. I am already having the encrypted value with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely several errors here, and it's unclear what your `-crypt:iv:key:context:` method does. Do you know for certain that your encryption system exactly matches your `-crypt:iv:key:context:` method?

At a start, you're getting nil because the output isn't UTF-8 (because it's almost certainly corrupted due to passing the wrong key and IV).

Next, your crypt method should be generating errors because what you're passing is invalid, so you need to check those errors. They would likely tell you what's wrong.

At a minimum, you are decoding the key and IV incorrectly. If they're in Base64, they're the wrong length. They look like they're just UTF-8/ASCII encoded (which is a security issue, but your system may just be insecure). In Base64, this key is 24 bytes, while in ASCII it's 32 bytes (which is the correct key length).

If that's the only problem, then the fix would be:

```
NSData *key   = [base64Key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *keyiv = [base64KeyIv dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

(Ideally you'd rename the "base64..." identifier since these aren't Base64 encoded. `dataString` does appear to be Base64 encoded.)